# Installing windows 7 after a kubuntu install?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, kubuntu

I have a kubuntu 12.10 installation that I use as a primary work machine.  This is a single installation (2 partition OS / Swap).

I need to install windows7 and the majority of tutorials (all) assume that windows is installed first.

Is it possible to use the kde partition manager to shrink the kubuntu partition, add the two required windows partitions and install a 'working' windows7 install?

Do any tutorials exists as I imagine this might be messy...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to shrink your partition you'll need a `LiveUSB` boot to do that, because otherwise those partitions would be mounted and in-use (locked).

After you've shrunken your partition, and set-up a new one for `Windows` (do it carefully as shuffling/resizing partitions after an install is just a pain and can get risky), you can install `Windows` safely without losing your `Kubuntu` setup.

Just make sure you don't let the Windows installer overwrite/format/delete any of your `Kubuntu` partitions in the process.

After `Windows` is installed, the `MBR` of your hard-disk will be overwritten, thus deleting `Grub`. And you won't be able to boot into `Kubuntu`. This can easily be fixed though, through yet again a `LiveUSB` boot.

You can check out [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2) guide to find out instructions to restoring `Grub`.

As always, read up instructions before doing anything. If you're not sure about something, Google for step-by-step instructions, read it, *then* ask new questions :)